# How to fix "only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices" in this example

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, normalization, scaling

I have the following type of data.

```
InvoiceNo   InvoiceDate InvoiceType PriceType   SellManNo   CustomerNo  PaymentDate Total
91          1/15/2019   4           2           1           700         1/15/2019   1140.55
92          1/15/2019   4           2           1           13          1/15/2019   201
93          1/15/2019   4           2           1           675         1/15/2019   500
94          1/15/2019   4           2           1           456         1/15/2019   48
95          1/15/2019   4           2           1           709         1/15/2019   276
96          1/15/2019   4           2           1           98          2/14/2019   299
97          1/15/2019   1           2           1           1           1/15/2019   45.66
98          1/15/2019   4           2           1           478         1/15/2019   2.88
```

This is what I tried:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
scaling=MinMaxScaler()
df_total=df[['Total']]

df_total=scaling.fit_transform(df_total)

df_total
```

And I got the error.

```
only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

Comment: Meaning, that the maximum value from `Total` is determined, and then everything in `Total` is divided by that?

Comment: But I don't understand how the title you've given for this question has anything to do with the question you actually asked. If you tried to write some code that gave you that error message, you should *show the code*. We can't tell you what's wrong with code that we can't see.

Comment: I want to transform the values of Total in between 0 and 1?

Comment: Normalization is a well-documented computation.  Where is the code that is giving you trouble?  Post the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: "I want to transform the values of Total in between 0 and 1?" Okay, and what is the rule that tells you what "value between 0 and 1" you should get, for each input?

Comment: Oh, well, you should have mentioned something about using sklearn. Wait, why would you be using sklearn just to manipulate some tables? I thought that was for neural-network stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you should need is:

```
df['Total'] /= max(df['Total'])
```

Comment: Yes this do the trick, but can I achieve it with a library function? The problem is, I used MinMaxScalar and its gives me that error. Why is that?

Comment: `df['Total'] /= df['Total'].max()` would be faster(for large `df`s) I guess.

Comment: I didn't think to check that there was such a method. Would be nice if Python supported some kind of hook so that `max` can do optimized things where appropriate.